# Interfacing Vector(VN1610) CAN Simulator with an OBD reader (Freematics One+ B)

Tags: can

I am using a Freematics One+ B for my project and to avoid developing and testing in a car, i would like to simulate ODB messages. I already have a Vector CAN emulator (VN1610) which creates proper CAN messages.

The problem i am facing is, the CAN emulator i have just provides a GND,CAN_ HIGH and CAN_LOW. On the other hand, the ODB scanner (Freematics One+ B) has  more pins that connect with the actual Car ODB port, namely:

- 4,5 : signal ground and chassis ground (i will hook them together for now)
- 6,14 : CAN_H, CAN_L (goes to corresponding can pins)
- 7,15, ... : Other vendor specific pins such as IS0 9141 (not related)
- 16 : Battery Voltage 12V

My question is, do i also need to hook up an external 12V battery to Pin 16 for this to work, or is there something i am missing and its not even possible to do this.

Comment: Yes, you will have to hook it up, the +12V is the supply for the Freematics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CAN bus part of the Freematics board is powered through the 12V pin of the OBD connector. The signal is manipulated with a series of cascaded step down converters to fit the power needs of the rest of the circuit. You can follow it from the [schematic](https://freematics.com/dl/schematics_oneplus_r14_20190612.pdf).

In short yes you need to connect the 12V pin.